# I am trying to update the data source of an oledb data adapter and nothing happens

Tags: powershell, oledbdataadapter

I am attempting to update data in an oledb datasource. I pull data from a table that who's schema has been written out as an access create table script (i could probably find a better way to get that schema information) and stored in the AccessCreateScript field of the lookup table.

I am able get the following things to work:

- pull the data out of the source table on sql server
- put it into a dataset
- verify its good
- create a second dataset based off the created table on the access file
- copy the data from the source dataset to the destination dataset
- verify that the data has been copied
- create the update command using a command builder
- verify the commands look correct

But, then when it comes to using the update method on the ole data adapter, it just doesnt do anything.

The data contained in the lookup table has been validated to be correct thoroughly.

There currently is only one record in the lookup table.

```
$LookupServer = "Redacted"
$LookupDatabase = "redacted"
    $LookupSQL = "Select [DBServer]
    ,[SourceDB]
    ,[SourceTableOrScript]
    ,[DestinationFile]
    ,[DestinationTable]
    ,[AccessDropScript]
    ,[AccessCreateScript]
    ,[Active]
    FROM [AccessDataExport_Lookup_Data]"
$LookupConnection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$LookupCSBuilder = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
$LookupCSBuilder['server'] = $LookupServer
$LookupCSBuilder['trusted_connection'] = $True
$LookupCSBuilder['database'] = $LookupDatabase
$LookupConnection.ConnectionString = $LookupCSBuilder.ConnectionString 
$LookupConnection.Open()
$LookupCommand = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$LookupCommand.Connection = $LookupConnection
$LookupCommand.CommandText = $LookupSQL
$LookupDataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $LookupCommand
$LookupDataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$LookupDataAdapter.Fill($LookupDataset)
$LookupConnection.Close()

foreach( $r in $LookupDataset.Tables[0].Rows){

    $SourceConnection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $SourceCSBuilder = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    $SourceCSBuilder['server'] = $r.DBServer
    $SourceCSBuilder['trusted_connection'] = $true
    $SourceCSBuilder['database'] = $r.SourceDB
    $SourceConnection.ConnectionString = $SourceCSBuilder.ConnectionString
    $SourceCmd = $SourceConnection.CreateCommand()

    $DestConnection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
    $DestCSBuilder = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
    $DestCSBuilder['Provider'] = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
    $DestCSBuilder['Persist Security Info'] = $false
    $DestCSBuilder['Data Source'] = $r.DestinationFile
    $DestConnection.ConnectionString = $DestCSBuilder.ConnectionString
    $DestCmd = $DestConnection.CreateCommand()

    $DestConnection.Open()
    $SourceConnection.Open()

    $DestCmd.CommandText = $r.AccessDropScript
    try
    {
        $DestCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
    catch
    {
        write-Output $_.Exception.Message
        write-Output  $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    }
    $DestCmd.CommandText = $r.AccessCreateScript
    try{
        $DestCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        $SourceCmd.CommandText = $r.SourceTableOrScript
        $SourceDA = New-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SourceCmd
        $SourceData = new-object System.Data.Dataset

        $DestCmd.CommandText = $r.SourceTableOrScript
        $DestDA = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $DestCmd 
        $DestData = new-object System.Data.Dataset

        $result = $SourceDA.fill($SourceData)
        Write-Output "Source filled $result rows"   

        $result = $DestDA.fill($DestData)
        Write-Output "Dest filled $result rows" 

        $DestData.load($SourceData.CreateDataReader(),1,$SourceData.Tables[0].TableName)
        $destRowCount = $DestData.Tables[0].Rows.Count
        Write-Output "DestData Row Count $destrowcount"
        $DestCb = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder $DestDA

        $DestDA.UpdateCommand = $DestCb.GetUpdateCommand()
        $DestDA.InsertCommand = $DestCb.GetInsertCommand()
        $DestDA.DeleteCommand = $DestCb.GetDeleteCommand()

        $result = $DestDA.Update($DestData)
        Write-Output "Copy data copied $result rows"
    }
    Catch
    {
        write-Output  $_.Exception.Message
        write-Output  $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber
    }
    finally{
    $DestConnection.Close()
    $SourceConnection.Close()
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
PS C:\Users\****> & 'c:\Users\***\source\repos\Powershell Scripts\Modular-Export.ps1'
1
0
0
Source filled 1274 rows
Dest filled 0 rows
DestData Row Count 1274
Copy data copied 0 rows
```

Table data since this is pertinate, but with redacted sensitive information.
https://gist.github.com/KySoto/5a764f3fa3c0d139131056ed6d44529b

Answer (score -1):

In the end a reddit user helped me figure it out, Their [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/ctla6o/i_am_trying_to_update_the_data_source_of_an_oledb/exmt625/) was the thing that got everything rolling. What i needed to do was set the state of every datarow in my datatable to "Added" using the SetAdded method. Then i needed to set `$DestCb.QuotePrefix = "["` and `$DestCb.QuoteSuffix = "]"` Then it properly filled.